# Adding a Hyperlink to a new sheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I need to be able to auto add a Hyperlink to a worksheet in the same workbook.

The code below created a new report and names it according to the active cell on the Main page.

I want to Hyperlink that cell to the newly created sheet with the same name.

```vb
Sub New_sheet()
    Dim ShtName As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg
    ShtName = ActiveCell.Value2 ' <-- save the value of the ActiveCell
    Set ws = Sheets("Blank incident tab")
    ws.Copy After:=Sheets("Incident Catagories")
    Set wsNew = Sheets(Sheets("Incident Catagories").Index + 1)
    wsNew.Name = ShtName
    Exit Sub

    ErrMsg:

    MsgBox ("That incident report already Exsists, Please chaeck and open a new incident"), , "Error Duplicate incident"

    Sheets("Blank incident tab (2)").Delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you'll have more chance to get help if you show your attempts

Comment: You can record a macro and get the basic syntax for creating a link.

Comment: Thanks Tim I’ll give that a try